# how to correct merge rasters with different projections?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, merge

how to merge rasters with different projections with correct transforn? For example  EPSG:32636 and EPSG:32637

if i do it with gdal_retile command, i have correct view for EPSG:32637 rasters and uncorrect for EPSG:32636

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Can you please extend your question (just click edit below the question) with a bit more context, such as what format the rasters are, how you intend to combine them (join, overlap, merge), and what you've already tried (e.g. exact command line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to reproject one of your raster into the projection of your second raster.

EDIT : as mentioned by BradHart, this may cause severe distortions if you have a large E-W swath. In this case you should project both raster to a third projection (e.g. EPSG 3857 at low latitude, conic at mid latitude or azimuthal near the pole). See [here](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm) for more details.

Comment: projecting information outside its UTM zone may produce strange results. In this case they are adjacent, but another projection may be better.